# Derive cryptographic key from authentication provider

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, cryptography, openid

My users authenticate via OpenID Connect, an authentication extension to OAuth2.

I'd like to secure my users' data by encrypting it using a key only they hold (not me).

In terms of repeatable state, all I get from OpenID Connect is a deterministic `sub` (subject) field. Which is a public identifier, hence unsuitable for key derivation.

Is there any mechanism or flow supported in the OpenID Connect or OAuth2 standards that will allow a user to either:

- share a secret with me (upon login).
- cryptographically sign a message for me.

I have been reading and searching and I just cannot believe that this requirement is not covered somewhere.

Maybe there exists a different protocol that is equally widespread and supported by common OAuth2 providers like Google, Microsoft, etc?

Any pointers will help. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about [creating a secure protocol](https://security.stackexchange.com), not programming.